# Where does meteor stores its packages?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor 1.0 app. I've added a bunch of packages, for example: `meteor add kevohagan:ramda`. But I cannot find it anywhere. I can't even find it on my system.

In my project:

```
$> meteor list
kevohagan:ramda   0.1.2  A practical functional library for Javascript programmers.
meteor-platform   1.2.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
...

$> ls packages
ls: packages: No such file or directory

$> mdfind ramda.js # file added by the package
# no results
```

Where are they ?

Answer (score 6):

If you add a package via `meteor add author:pkg` it will be added to the meteor installation (e.g. `~/.meteor/packages`); here you can find different versions of the package. In your project home, the package name will be added to the `.meteor/packages` file.

Later, if run your project, the package will be added to the `build` directory (and of course only one version can be found here).

Comment: They indeed are in `.meteor/packages`. I would like my editor to be able to parse them for indentation, jump to declaration and the like. It is possible to tell meteor to add them in a local `packages` folder ?

Comment: @pinouchon: I use WebStorm and add "external libraries", pointing to source directories. You can add anything that way, [Google Maps for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26579776/1269037). What IDE do you use?

Comment: There is a possibility to have a local packed directory (to be used if you forked your own yet unpublished version). This will overwrite the global package (at least this was the case before 1.0). Not sure if I would use this approach "just" to have a better editor experience. Symlinks could be an option (haven't tried it yet).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I have added ~/.meteor/packages as an external library. But to me this is a really bad idea. Because I have each version of each package, for each environment (web, client, cordova, etc). For example, I have 5 identical places to go to, just to see the declaration of `ramda`, all identical. Meteor 0.9.4 used to create a packages directory with symbolic links pointing to the right place. Can I tell meteor to create symlinks for installed packages in my app ?

Comment: `C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Local\.meteor` for Windows users

Comment: Nov 2016: This is one of these questions which will pop up for a google search ("where does meteor store packages") and the answer is not  correct anymore. Look at ```.meteor/local/build/programs/{server|web.browser}``` (for server or client packages).   Mac OS/Linux and Meteor v. 1.4.2

Comment: Are you sure? I tested w Meteor 1.4.2. If you download a package from atmospherejs they're still under ~/.meteor/packges.

Comment: After running 'meteor' the local build however is at <appdir>/.meteor/local/build/programs/{server|web.browser} (but that's a different thing).

Answer (score 1):

I think that they all are in

```
.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages
```

but they are ninified, and the file names are changed, like "**kevohagan_ramda.js**" or "**meteor-platform.js**"

Answer (score 0):

If you check out your project folder then you'll find two 'packages' folders. One at the root of your project and the other deep down inside `.meteor`. Below I've listed both of them.

```
.meteor/packages  //this consist of the packages that you built yourself or other top-level packages like spinner & iron:router
.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages   //other packages
```

Comment: In meteor 1.0, `.meteor/packages` is a file containing the name of the packages