# Where does Meteor stores packages

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662427/where-does-meteor-stores-its-packages), but I still can't understand. I added [materialize](https://atmospherejs.com/materialize/materialize) to my project and would like to look at it's css files. But can't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As indicated on atmosphere, the current build is failing. Maybe this has something to do with its disappearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmosphere packages are stored a bit differently on the client. They don't quite have separate js/css/etc files like NPM packages do. Take a look at your `.meteor\local\bundler-cache\linker` directory, and you'll find a lot of `.cache` files that are basically representations of entire packages.

Check out their GitHub page instead: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize